# Does Eclipse have a "Select in Projects" option like NetBeans?

Tags: eclipse

Does Eclipse support "Select in Projects" option like NetBeans?

It opens the file in the project hierarchy in the "Project Explorer" left window.

Comment: Have you tried it? For those who don't have NetBeans, can you explain what it does?

Comment: @slhck It opens file in project hierarchy in project explorer left window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has an option under *Navigate* to show the currently selected function (or class) in the Project Explorer or Package Explorer, as well as several other windows.

[image]

To set a keyboard shortcut to this specific item, go to the *Keys* preferences under *General*.

[image]

Comment: Is there a shortcut for directly doing show in project explorer ?

Comment: See updated answer